# Install and use RMQClient with Swift

Tags: swift, sockets

I'm trying to use RMQClient in my Swift project.

I've install with Cocoapods, and I importing the module:

[View code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNUGh.png)

But XCODE returns "Cannot find 'RMQConnection' in scope".
Anybody can help me?

Install and import RMQCLIENT